# Controls on a second column with FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm adding some control to a FlowLayoutPanel in top to bottom mode, but when I do that, if I add too many button, they appear outside the window.

If we compare that to a table, controls appear on many rows on 1 column

I just want the FlowLayoutPanel add the control on a second "column" at the right of other.

Is it possible? I don't want scrollbars

I'm using the FlowLayoutPanel in a **UserControl** which is added dynamicaly. So maybe it's a problem with the size...

Thank

Answer (score 2):

FlowLayoutPanel should do this by default.

Check that the `WrapContents` property is set to `True`, and `AutoSize` is set to `False`.

If it is still not wrapping, it most likely does not have enough room to create a second column.

To test, make the panel wider.

If scrollbars are appearing for you, make sure the `AutoScroll` property is set to false.

Comment: Since I pass AutoSize to False, the FlowLayoutPanel keep is original size and I can't see the controls in

Comment: @FRO set the size you want the panel to be manually. If you want it expanding with the window, also set the appropriate anchors.

Comment: And if you want it to autosize, but only up to a certain size, set the appropriate `MaximumSize`

Comment: @user122211: Yes but if I do that I can't center my FlowLayoutPanel because it doesn't have a size which corresponding to the controls place taken

Comment: @FRO it appears you have additional requirements (e.g. centering) which wasn't mentioned in the original question. Could you post some more details?

Comment: @user122211: Yes I think I have forgot to say I'm using it in a UserControl

Comment: @FRO if I understand you correctly, you want it to be centred in some other control when it is one column, and once it goes to two columns, you want it to re-centre again?

Comment: @user122211: I want to center the FlowLayoutPanel wich is autosized with the buttons I'm adding dynamicaly. And I want the buttons appear on one or two column if needed, not outside the clientscreen. The autosize seems not work in my case

Comment: @user122211: Ok I simulate operation with a button and it's ok, so I think it's because I add buttons when I'm in the Load() method of my UserControl